# Convert a project folder into its own project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there any cool trick to take a subfolder in visual studio and make it it's own project in that folder namespace?  My assembly has gotten rather large and it's time for a refactor.  I could do it manually but it seems like there would be a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to exclude those files from the project, move them into their own folder, and use the New Project from Existing Code wizard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx